# Realtime-notifications with ajax

Tags: php, ajax, laravel, notifications

Hello i'm a new developer and  in my laravel project i have implemented a real time chat function with ajax but i also want to add a real time notification system with ajax so when a message is written all users are notified for that message it would be very helpful if you could help me

here's my index page :

```
@extends('admin.app')
@section('content')
    <div class="container">
        <div class="row" style ="padding-top:40px;">
            <h3 class="text-center">Welcome {{Auth::user()->FullName}}</h3>
            <br/><br/>
            <div class="col-md-2">
                    <p>Users online</p>
                    @foreach($users as $user)
                        @if($user->isOnline())
                            <li>{{$user->FullName}}</li>
                        @endif
                    @endforeach


            </div>

            <div class="col-md-8">
                <div class="panel panel-info">
                    <div class="panel-heading">
                        Recent Chat
                    </div>
                    <div class="panel-body">
                        <ul class="media-list" id="message">

                            @foreach($messages as $message )
                                <li class="media">
                                    <div class="media-body">
                                        <div class="media">

                                            <div class="media-body" >
                                                {{$message->message}}
                                                <br/>
                                               <bold> <small class="text-muted">{{$message->from_name}} |{{$message->created_at}}
                                                   </small></bold>
                                                <hr>
                                            </div>
                                        </div>
                                    </div>
                                </li>


                            @endforeach
                        </ul>
                        <div>
                            <div class="panel-footer">
                                <div class="input-group">
                                    <input type="text" name="message" class="form-control" placeholder="Enter Message"/>
                                    {{csrf_field()}}
                                    <input type="hidden" name="from_name" value="{{Auth::user()->FullName}}">
                                    <span class="input-group-btn">
                                    <button type="submit" id="send" class="btn btn-info">Send</button>
                                </span>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                        <div class="col-md-2">

                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>

    <script type="text/javascript" src="/assets/admin/plugins/jquery/jquery-1.9.1.min.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript">
        $(document).ready(function(){
            setTimeout(realTime, 2000);
        });
        function realTime() {
            $.ajax({
                type:'post',
                url:'/chat/get',
                data:{
                    '_token':$('input[name=_token]').val(),
                },
                success: function (data) {
                    $('#message').replaceWith(' <ul class="media-list" id="message"></ul>');
                    for (var i=0; i < data.length; i++){
                        $('#message').append(' <li class="media"><div class="media-body"><div class="media"><div class="media-body">'+data[i].message+'<br/><small class="text-muted">'+data[i].from_name+'|'+ data[i].created_at+'</small><hr/></div></div></div></li>')
                    }
                },
            });
            setTimeout(realTime, 2000);
        }
        $(document).on('click','#send', function (){
            $.ajax({
                type:'post',
                url:'/chat/send',
                data:{
                    '_token':$('input[name=_token]').val(),
                    'from_name':$('input[name=from_name]').val(),
                    'message':$('input[name=message]').val(),
                },
                success: function (data) {
                  $('#message').append('  <li class="media"><div class="media-body"><div class="media"><div class="media-body">'+data.message+'<br/><small class="text-muted">'+data.from_name+'|'+ data.created_at+'</small><hr/></div></div></div></li>');
                }
            })

            $('input[name=message]').val('');
        });

    </script>

@stop
```

here's my routes :

```
Route::get('/chat', 'Chat\ChatController@index')->name('chat.index');
Route::post('/chat/send', 'Chat\ChatController@sendMessage' )->name('admin.chat.sendMessage');
Route::post('/chat/get', 'Chat\ChatController@getMessage' );
```

here's my controllers:

```
 public function __construct()
    {
        $this->middleware('auth');
    }

    public function index()
    {
        $users=user::all();
        $messages=message::all();
        return view('admin.chat.index',['messages'=> $messages],compact('users'));
    }

    public function sendMessage(Request $request){

        $send = new Message();
        $send ->from_name = $request->from_name;
        $send ->message = $request->message;
        $send->save();
        return response()->json($send);

    }

    public function  getMessage(){
        $message = Message::all();
        return response()->json($message);

    }
```

Sorry in advanced for the bad english but i am a foreigner

Comment: If you have already implemented a chat app then what issue or confusion do you have with live notificaion? you can do it toastr and ajax or you can try pusher https://pusher.com/tutorials pusher can be used to implement not just notification but live chat itself

Comment: well i don't know how to go about it,how can i write the code                            i have tried to  install pusher but i don't have php-curl so it wont install

Comment: do you think ajax is good for real time chat application

Comment: @kunal I agree it is not: websockets is the way to go for "realtime" notifications. Ajax is just not suited / fast enough for this task.

Comment: well that  was my only option because  when i used pusher or vuejs  they didn't work and i found a good tutorial about it

Comment: what do you mean by they didn't work.. google out and study about pusher tutorial there are many tutorial it wil help you

Comment: yeah but it didnt install in my project because i didnt have php-curl and i didn't know how to install it

Comment: https://blog.pusher.com/how-to-build-a-laravel-chat-app-with-pusher/ try this tutorial if you use ajax for chat it will give you more problem in future

Answer (score 0, accepted):

***well you have to read this tutorial and implement like this....***

https://laracasts.com/discuss/channels/general-discussion/step-by-step-guide-to-installing-socketio-and-broadcasting-events-with-laravel-51

Comment: Welcome to Stackoverflow! Please provide an explanation and/or examples with your answers, as a single link to a documentation might not be as useful.

Answer (score 0):

```
   $(window).load(realTime);
    function realTime() {
        $.ajax({
            type:'post',
            url:'/chat/get',
            data:{
                '_token':$('input[name=_token]').val(),
            },
            success: function (data) {
                $('#message').replaceWith(' <ul class="media-list" id="message"></ul>');
                for (var i=0; i < data.length; i++){
                    $('#message').append(' <li class="media"><div class="media-body"><div class="media"><div class="media-body">'+data[i].message+'<br/><small class="text-muted">'+data[i].from_name+'|'+ data[i].created_at+'</small><hr/></div></div></div></li>')
                }
             setTimeout(realTime, 2000);
            },
        });

    }
}
```

Try this..

Comment: I know it is bad.. but the as per questionnaire, he is asking ajax call for that option. that is why i opted this answer.